# XSLT Choose Not working

Tags: xml, xslt

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  When `<xsl:value-of select="string-length(add:Destinations/add:DestinationName)" />` = Sacramento, CA I would expect the variable region to be west, but I get east.

```
<xsl:variable name="charCount">
  <xsl:value-of select="string-length(add:Destinations/add:DestinationName)" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="amendedCharCount">
    <xsl:value-of select="$charCount - 2"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="state">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(add:Destinations/add:DestinationName,$amendedCharCount)"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="region">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$state='CA'">west</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>east</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>    
<xsl:element name="OperationsRegion">
  <xsl:value-of select="$region"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: You should really have posted your input XML in the question too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT/XPath, the indexing of characters in a string is 1-based, not 0-based. So, instead of doing this (which will actually get the last three characters)

```
 <xsl:variable name="amendedCharCount"><xsl:value-of select="$charCount - 2"/></xsl:variable>
```

Do this....

```
 <xsl:variable name="amendedCharCount"><xsl:value-of select="$charCount - 1"/></xsl:variable>
```

Or better still, do this....

```
<xsl:variable name="amendedCharCount" select="$charCount - 1"/>
```

Perhaps, if all your destinations have the same format, you could also simplify the three expressions into one? This would work if there was only ever one comma in the destination name.

```
<xsl:variable name="state" select="substring-after(add:Destinations/add:DestinationName, ', ')" />
```

Comment: <xsl:variable name="state" select="substring-after(add:Destinations/add:DestinationName, ', ')" /> works perfectly.  Way more simplified solution than I was doing.  Thanks so much!

Comment: And also - thanks for the explanation as to why this wasn't working. I see my mistake now.